# Jenkins Build Time Trend API does not yield output using curl API

Tags: json, curl, jenkins

I got this link to get the Build Time Trend along with other Data in jenkins

```
https://jenkins:8080/view/<view-name>/job/<job-name>/<buildnumber>/api/json
```

This works well in a web browser but this does not seem to work with curl, does not give any result when I run along with curl command

This is what I tried

```
curl -u user:api_token -s -k "https://jenkins:8080/view/<view-name>/job/<job-name>/<buildnumber>/api/json"
```

This syntax worked with other API's.

Not sure what is wrong here.

```
curl -u userid:api_token -s -k "https://jenkins:8080/view/<view-name>/job/<job-name>/<buildnumber>/api/json" | jq.'causes[]|{result}'

jq.causes[]|{result}: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between `jq` and its arguments (and probably not a period).

```
... | jq 'causes[]|{result}'
        ^
        space here
```